# Writing an external program to interface with wpa_supplicant in C++

Tags: c++, linux, arm, linux-device-driver, android-wifi

As I understand it one can simply link wpa_ctrl.c into an external program and then you are able to use it's functions to control and receive information from wpa_supplicant.

Could someone please provide an example, preferably in C++, how you would:

1. Link the external program to the wpa_ctrl.c file.
2. What the code would look like to do a 'scan' and then print 'scan_results'.

I'm new to coding on an embedded linux platform and there are no examples of this anywhere. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The program [`wpa_cli`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli) is an example of exactly what you want.  The *wpa_supplicant* project support the `V=1` option to see what is needed to create this executable.  Here is the result for my ARM build,

```
gcc -c -o wpa_cli.o -MMD -O2 -Wall -g -I src -I src/utils \
  -Iusr_ARM/include/libnl3 \
  -DCONFIG_BACKEND_FILE -DCONFIG_IEEE80211W  -DCONFIG_DRIVER_WEXT \
  -DCONFIG_WIRELESS_EXTENSION  -DCONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211 -DCONFIG_LIBNL20 \
  -DEAP_PSK -DIEEE8021X_EAPOL -DCONFIG_SHA256 -DCONFIG_CTRL_IFACE \
  -DCONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_UNIX  -DCONFIG_SME \
   wpa_cli.c

gcc  -o wpa_cli wpa_cli.o ../src/common/wpa_ctrl.o ../src/utils/wpa_debug.o \
   ../src/utils/common.o ../src/utils/os_unix.o ../src/utils/eloop.o \
   ../src/utils/edit_simple.o -lrt
```

Substitute your paths to get *headers* for the version of the *wpa_supplicant* used on your target ARM device (in the first command).  Link with all of the *object* files listed in the second command and link with the *real-time* library (with `-lrt`).  You can also look at the [*wpa_cli.c*](http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli.c) for your version of the *wpa_supplicant* to get examples of how to send commands to the supplicant process.

The object list includes *wpa_ctrl.o* (as you guessed) and many others.  Some of them may not be needed, depending on features you use, but I would start with the complete list and then trim them after you have a functioning example.

The license is the generous BSD on this source.

Here is [wpa_cli_cmd_scan()](http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli.c#n1484) which sends the *scan* request,

```
static int wpa_cli_cmd_scan(struct wpa_ctrl *ctrl, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return wpa_cli_cmd(ctrl, "SCAN", 0, argc, argv);
}
```

You probably also want the `scan_results`; it is in the same file as `wpa_cli_cmd_scan_results()`.

The API is also [well documented under **wpa_supplicant control interface**](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html), where you can extend your working example.  Make sure you get source that matches the version of the *wpa_supplicant* in use on your system.  The commands above are for an *eglibc* Linux system; It looks like bionic (Android library) supplies the `-lrt` by default. If you can run the commands, `rm wpa_cli.o; rm wpa_cli; make V=1` in the *wpa_supplicant* directory of a build for your device you will see the exact commands needed.

You probably don't need the *edit_simple.o* file.  However, the *eloop* is likely needed to get unsolicited events from the drivers when the scan request is completed; at least if you want to work with many different Wifi chips.  The steps are,

1. Send `SCAN`.
2. Wait for *<SCAN_COMPLETE>*.
3. Send `SCAN_RESULTS`.